# Converting PHP array to C# when calling API

Tags: c#, php, json

I've looked at several related examples on SO and tried a number of methods to get this to work, but I become more confused with each attempt.

I'm trying to search through the Wordpress.org plugin repository API and get a list of plugins from the search results.

The endpoint is: http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/

The two important bits of data to pass are "action" and "search." The action I'm interested in at the moment is "query_plugins", and passing a search string along in the request.

This is a PHP equivalent:

```
$payload = array(
  'action' => 'query_plugins',
  'request' => serialize(
    (object)array(
        'search ' => 'search-phrase',
    )
  )
);
$body = wp_remote_post( 'http://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/', array( 'body' => $payload) );
```

The only real documentation I've been able to find is from this blog post (which is where I got the above sample code): https://dd32.id.au/projects/wordpressorg-plugin-information-api-docs/

I'm using RestSharp to build the request, with code along these lines:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.wordpress.org/");
var request = new RestRequest("plugins/info/1.0", Method.POST);

request.AddParameter("XXX", "XXX");

var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

the "request.AddParameter("XXX", "XXX"); above is where I'm stuck. I need to build the PHP array equivalent in C# (and serialize it properly?) so that the API will accept the request. I've tried several variants and combinations, from everything as primitive as:

```
request.AddParameter("action", "query_plugins");
request.AddParameter("search", "keyword");
// and variants such as request.AddParameter("request", "[{ search: keyword }]);
```

Which I knew wouldn't work (but took a stab with anyway), to using a Dictionary() with the action and search parameters, and attempting to serialize it in several ways (most recent involved JsonConvert.SerializeObject).

At this point I don't know which tree I should be barking up, I have a feeling I'm not even in the right vicinity. I'm not even sure if I should be serializing to JSON, XML, or just a byte-stream (as I understand that's what the PHP serialize() method does, if I'm not mistaken), and I'm not sure the best approach to package all of the data I need to send off in the request.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. Instead of POST, use GET

See the working sample here..
https://dotnetfiddle.net/rvL9eC

```
var client = new RestClient("http://api.wordpress.org/");
var request = new RestRequest("plugins/info/1.0", Method.GET);

request.AddParameter("action", "query_plugins");
request.AddParameter("search", "oauth");

var response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, and apologies for the delayed reply. However, it seems that no matter what you use for AddParameter("search", "XXX") it always returns the same response in .NET Fiddle. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I just now tried the fiddle with "oauth" and then with "two factor" and i am getting different response. Check the first line, it should be different

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D9fDdx for the second search and i can see the response is different. Moreover there are some bits in the response are similar but the list of plugins are different